# How to i insert a JSON object into an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have a JSON

```
"passengers": [{
        "accompaniedByInfant": true,
        "birthDate": {
            "day": 6,
            "fractionalSecond": 0.000,
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "month": 9,
            "orig_day": 6,
            "orig_fracSeconds": 0.000,
            "orig_hour": 0,
            "orig_minute": 0,
            "orig_month": 9,
            "orig_second": 0,
            "orig_timezone": 330,
            "orig_year": 1991,
            "second": 0,
            "timezone": 330,
            "year": 1991
        },
        "hasStrecher": false,
        "parentSequence": 0,
        "passengerTypeCode": "ADLT",
                "gender":"M" 
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "v",
            "nameTitle": "MR",  
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "j"
        },
        "requestedSeatCount": 1,
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "unaccompaniedMinor": false
    }, {
        "accompaniedByInfant": false,
        "birthDate": {
            "day": 10,
            "fractionalSecond": 0.000,
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "month": 10,
            "orig_day": 10,
            "orig_fracSeconds": 0.000,
            "orig_hour": 0,
            "orig_minute": 0,
            "orig_month": 10,
            "orig_second": 0,
            "orig_timezone": 330,
            "orig_year": 2010,
            "second": 0,
            "timezone": 330,
            "year": 2010
        },
        "hasStrecher": false,
        "parentSequence": 0,
        "passengerTypeCode": "CHLD",
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "some",
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "child"
        },
        "requestedSeatCount": 1,
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "unaccompaniedMinor": false
    },
```

and so on depending on the number of passengers.

I have to sent this to the server in

```
let param : [String: Any] =[ "passengers":passengerparameterarray,"pwd": password,"requestPurpose": "MODIFY_PERMANENTLY_AND_CALC","unm": username ]
```

Here `passengerparameterarray` is an array of type string.(here is the issue). I stored details of each passenger in an array 
`paramarray` and whenever user finishes adding details, `paramarray` is added to the `passengerparameterarray` on position depending on the `indexPath`. (1 passenger = added on 0th index, 2 = on 0th and 1st index and so on).

But when I send it to server it goes like

```
"passengers" : [ [ .....  ] ]
```

This gives me error as I have an array inside of the array. How do I fix this? I try changing to string but that gives me error as String isn't JSON object because of the `"` coming before `{` .

I converted each array to JSON Object. But how do i JSON Object the main array? As the Main array is `[String]()` . If i try changing to `[String:Any]()` , things like

```
array.insert()
```

Wont work.

How do I fix this? I want to add the JSON object into an array and then sent it to the server.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting from the server when you pass ```let param : [String: Any] =[ "passengers":passengerparameterarray,"pwd": password,"requestPurpose": "MODIFY_PERMANENTLY_AND_CALC","unm": username ]``` in the api request.

Comment: @AnkushBhatia Its an error telling me that i have an array inside the array and its not supposed to be there. 

[
  [
    {
 
      "personName" : {
        "shareMarketInd" : false,
        "nameTitle" : "MR",
        "givenName" : "aaaa",
        "surname" : "aaa"
      },
      "requestedSeatCount" : 1,
      "gender" : "M",
      "birthDate" : {
        "year" : "2019",
        "day" : "29",
        "month" : "5"
      },
      "parentSequence" : 0,
      "passengerTypeCode" : "ADLT",
      "shareMarketInd" : false
    }
  ]
]

Comment: Maybe you should send your Json in the body and not as a parameter

Comment: @AnkushBhatia The issue is that i have 2 [[ at the start and 2 ]] at the end. Its supposed to be [ ]  and i know this is because i insert my passengerdetails as [passengerdetails] into parameter array.

How can i insert my array having details of passengers into the main array as JSON objects?

Comment: Also, one passenger should not be stored in an array, it should be stored in a dictionary

Comment: @Zyfe3r Check my answer you need to update JSON parameters in param array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var param : [String:Any] = ["requestedSeatCount" : 1, "gender" : "M", "parentSequence" : 0, "passengerTypeCode" : "ADLT", "shareMarketInd" : false]

param.updateValue(["nameTitle" : "MR", "givenName" : "aaaa", "surname" : "aaa"], forKey: "personName")
param.updateValue(["year" : "2019", "day" : "29", "month" : "5"], forKey: "birthDate")
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid question. This all happened because originally my array was

```
var passengerparameterarray = [Array<Any>]()
```

instead of

```
var passengerparameterarray = Array<[String: Any]>()
```

Which as expected stopped me from inserting JSON object which is in the form of "String:Any"